# How to specify the compile order for a multi-module project in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, testing, intellij-idea, ide, multi-module

I have a multi-module project with test dependencies between modules.

Layout:

- main-module - has SpecialsTableQueryBuilderTest that depends on AbstractTestHelper from the generic-search module
- generic-search - has AbstractTestHelper

The problem: is that when I run "Make project" the SpecialsTableQueryBuilderTest class it complains that it "cannot find symbol, symbol: class AbstractTestHelper".

I tried in the modules settings, for the main-module, dependencies tab to move the generic-search module up, but it didn't help.

Another thing I tried on the same dependencies tab, it was to add the folder output for test-classes ("/target/test-classes")from the generic-search module as dependencie

What can I do so my project setup to see the AbstractTestHelper class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to build one project at a time, I suggest trying to run the test of interest.  This will build that class and everything it depends on (often a few classes you didn't really need) but it does all this for you.

If you are trying to include a class from a test module into another test module, you need to export it as this is not how maven projects work by default.  You can have maven also build it's tests into an additional jar which you can include as a dependency.

Here is instructions on how to build a test JAR http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in the end I just added the classes compiled from required-module/target/test-classes as provided to my dependencies list.

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question.

Comment: @PhilipRego it attempts to solve the problem. If you have an answer, please add it.